# redux-form initialValues

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I kinda getting lost here while i try to populate a redux-form V6.
I'm trying to create a contact form with person and company details. Since I'm new to the react universe I jump from one Doc/Tutorial to the other... So it may looks a bit scraped together.

1. I don't understand the concept how I can tell the Form that it has
   to submit a ID that is comming from "props.match.params.id".? Or is
   it just a bind and will get the result when i call **this.props.dispatch(getContact(this.props.match.params.id));** in the Contact Component?
2. The reducer returns a Object that has the Person and Company as
   "sub"-Object how can i match that to the Form?

Is there a way to debug the Form? I just see that my request returned a contact but i don't know if it even reaches the Form.

I use react-router to link to:

> /contacts/contact/:id -> Populated Contact Form

Because of the redux/routerv4 issues i have to wrap my React.Component in withRouter to get the params in props. I don't know how i can connect withRouter and mapDispatchToProps, So my Contact Component looks as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl';
import {getContact} from "../../../Actions/contactsActions";
import ContactForm from './Forms/ContactForm';

@connect((store) => {
    return {
        contacts: store.contacts,
        countries: store.countries,
        contactCategories: store.contactCategories
    }
})

class Contact extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            errors: {},
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        if(this.props.match.params.id) {
            this.props.dispatch(getContact(this.props.match.params.id));
        }
    }

    handleSubmit(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="contact-container">
                <ContactForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(Contact);
```

And the Form looks like:

```
    import React from 'react'
    import { connect } from 'react-redux'
    import { Field, reduxForm, formValueSelector } from 'redux-form'
    import { FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl';
    import {getContact} from "../../../../Actions/contactsActions";

    class ContactForm extends React.Component {
        render() {
            const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
            return (
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <div className="tab-pane fade show active" id="general" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="general-tab">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-lg-6 col-6">
                                <h2>
                                    <FormattedMessage id={ 'Company' } values={{name:"Company"}} />
                                </h2>
                                <div className="form-group row">
                                    <label htmlFor="company-name" className="col-4 col-form-label">
                                        <FormattedMessage id={ 'Companyname' } values={{name:"Company name"}} />
                                    </label>
                                    <div className="col-8">
                                        <Field component="input" className="form-control" name="company-name" placeholder="Company name" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group row">
                                    <label htmlFor="other-name" className="col-4 col-form-label">
                                        <FormattedMessage id={ 'Othername' } values={{name:"Other name"}} />
                                    </label>
                                    <div className="col-8">
                                        <Field component="input" className="form-control" name="other-name" placeholder="In case of sister company/group"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-lg-6 col-6">
                                <h2>
                                    <FormattedMessage id={ 'Person ' } values={{name:"Person"}} />
                                </h2>
                                <div className="form-group row">
                                    <label htmlFor="person-language" className="col-4 col-form-label">
                                        <FormattedMessage id={ 'Language' } values={{name:"Language"}} />
                                    </label>
                                    <div className="col-8">
                                        <Field component="select" className="form-control" name="person-language" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group row">
                                    <label htmlFor="person-gender" className="col-4 col-form-label">
                                        <FormattedMessage id={ 'Gender' } values={{name:"Gender"}} />
                                    </label>
                                    <div className="col-8">
                                        <Field component="select" className="form-control" name="person-gender">

                                        </Field>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group row">
                                    <label htmlFor="person-salutation" className="col-4 col-form-label">
                                        <FormattedMessage id={ 'Salutation' } values={{name:"Salutation"}} />
                                    </label>
                                    <div className="col-8">
                                        <Field component="select" className="form-control" name="person-salutation" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group row">
                                    <label htmlFor="person-title" className="col-4 col-form-label">
                                        <FormattedMessage id={ 'Title' } values={{name:"Title"}} />
                                    </label>
                                    <div className="col-8">
                                        <Field component="input" className="form-control" name="person-title" placeholder="Prof. Dr. Dr."/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group row">
                                    <label htmlFor="first-name" className="col-4 col-form-label">
                                        <FormattedMessage id={ 'First-name' } values={{name:"First name"}} />
                                    </label>
                                    <div className="col-8">
                                        <Field component="input" className="form-control" name="first-name" placeholder="First name"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group row">
                                    <label htmlFor="further-names" className="col-4 col-form-label">
                                        <FormattedMessage id={ 'Further-names' } values={{name:"Further names"}} />
                                    </label>
                                    <div className="col-8">
                                        <Field component="input" className="form-control" name="further-names" placeholder="Further names"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group row">
                                    <label htmlFor="last-name" className="col-4 col-form-label">
                                        <FormattedMessage id={ 'Last-name' } values={{name:"Last name"}} />
                                    </label>
                                    <div className="col-8">
                                        <Field component="input" className="form-control" name="last-name" placeholder="Last name"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group row">
                                    <label htmlFor="job-title" className="col-4 col-form-label">
                                        <FormattedMessage id={ 'Job-title' } values={{name:"Job title"}} />
                                    </label>
                                    <div className="col-8">
                                        <Field component="input" className="form-control" name="job-title" placeholder="Last name"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            )
        }
    }

const validate = (values) => {
    const errors = {};

    if(!values.Companyname) {
        errors.Companyname = "Enter a Companyname";
    }
    return errors;
};

ContactForm = reduxForm({
    validate,
    form: 'contact',
    enableReinitialize : true
})(ContactForm);

ContactForm = connect(
    state => ({
        initialValues: state.contacts.contacts
    }),
    { load: getContact }
)(ContactForm);

export default ContactForm;
```

Comment: I think you need the reducer instead of '{load:getcontact'}. Try putting in { reducer }. Also, for debugging, a good tool is the redux chrome dev tools extension. It helps with seeing the state and actions. Also make sure that the field names in the form match the keys of your initial values

Comment: Okay it was all correct what I've done. Somewhere in the redux-form migration DOC I found that you can name the Field like: "contact.Company.OtherName" and that solved my problem.